# Typescript - App.tsx is not under rootDir

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have just installed typescript for my react-native project and when I run the project, the following error message is displayed in the packager:

> error: bundling failed: Error: File
>   '/Users/user/React/Test/src/App.tsx' is not under
>   'rootDir' './src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

I have deleted the App.js file from the root of my project and I have created a new App.tsx in src/App.tsx so I cannot understand why is this happening.

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "jsx": "react",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "strict": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "dist",
    "__tests__"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I believe it's taking `./src` relative to where metro is running rather than relative to where you call it. I don't think this will work, but can you try `src/` instead of `./src`?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Thank you for the solution but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: You might try https://github.com/ds300/react-native-typescript-transformer ... you shouldn't need `outDir` or `rootDir`

Comment: @ExplosionPills I have tried that and I have managed to make it work, thank you. But I don't understand how is it going to convert tsx and ts files into js files when I want to create a standalone or development or release bundle? Because now it's not generating another folder where he puts the converted js files.

Comment: If you want to create the bundle do it through the `react-native bundle` command.